# Pandas Dataframe plot rows vs columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, data-visualization

I want to plot a DataFrame with football scores

```
Index | goals game 1| goals game 2| ....
Team 1| 2           | 3           | ....
Team 2| 4           | 1           | ....
```

So I want to plot goals vs. games for each team - how can I do that with `pandas.DataFrame.plot`?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'game 1':[4,5,2], 'game 2':[3,4,1], 'game 3':[3,2,2]}, index=['team a', 'team b', 'team c'])
>>> df
        game 1  game 2  game 3
team a       4       3       3
team b       5       4       2
team c       2       1       2

>>> df.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
df.T.plot(kind='line',subplots=True, figsize=(4,6))
```

[image]